# splitting strings in oracle sql based on length

Tags: sql, oracle

I want to split my strings in Oracle based on length with space as a delimiter.

For example,

```
MY_STRING="welcome to programming world"
```

My output should be

```
STRING1="welcome to "
STRING2="programming "
```

The strings should be a maximum of 13 characters in length. The words after position 26 can be ignored.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't mention what version of Oracle you're using. If you're using 10g or above you can use [regular expressions](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25518/adfns_regexp.htm#ADFNS1013) to get what you need:

```
with spaces as (
 select regexp_instr('welcome to programming world' || ' '
                    , '[[:space:]]', 1, level) as s
   from dual
connect by level <= regexp_count('welcome to programming world' || ' '
                                , '[[:space:]]')
        )
, actual as (
 select max(case when s <= 13 then s else 0 end) as a
      , max(case when s <= 26 then s else 0 end) as b
   from spaces
        )
select substr('welcome to programming world',1,a)
     , substr('welcome to programming world',a, b - a)
  from actual
```

This finds the positional index of all the spaces, then finds the one that's nearest but less than 14. Lastly uses a simple `substr` to split your string. The strings will have a trailing space so you might want to `trim` this.

You have to concatenate your string with a space to ensure that there is a trailing space so the last word doesn't get removed if your string is shorter than 26 characters.

Assuming you're using an earlier version you could hack something together with [`instr`](http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/instr.php) and `length` but it won't be very pretty at all.